# Error sending push notification from Kazoo's Pusher module with APNS

Tags: erlang, apple-push-notifications, push, kazoo

I've configured the Pusher Kazoo's application to wake up an iOS device before forward a voip call. I followed the official documentation [here](https://github.com/2600hz/kazoo/blob/master/applications/pusher/doc/pusher.md).

To send a push with APNS, Pusher use [this library](https://github.com/inaka/apns4erl) that works pretty well if I try it passing the parameters that Pusher should to.

Anyway, looking at Kazoo log, when Pusher try to send the push, an error is thrown during the connection with apns.

```
16:31:55.765 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|pm_apple:190(<0.5496.33>) error loading apns exit / {noproc,{gen_server,call,[apns_sup,{start_child,[#{apple_host => "api.push.apple.com",apple_port => 443,certdata => <<48,130,6,68,48,130,5,44,160,3,2,1,2,2,8,51,37,182,13,201,39,91,46,48,13,6,9,42,134,72,134,247,13,1,1,11,5,0,48,129,150,49,11,48,9,6,3,85,4,6,19,2,85,83,49,19,48,17,6,3,85,4,10,12,10,65,112,112,108,101,32,73,110,99,46,49,44,48,42,6,3,85,4,11,12,35,65,112,112,108,101,32,87,111,114,108,100,119,105,100,101,32,68,101,118,101,108,111,112,101,114,32,82,101,108,97,116,105,111,110,115,49,68,48,66,6,3,85,4,3,12,59,65,112,112,108,101,32,87,111,114,108,100,119,105,100,101,32,68,101,118,101,108,111,112,101,114,32,82,101,108,97,116,105,111,110,115,32,67,101,114,116,105,102,105,...>>,...},...]},...]}}
16:31:55.765 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:97(<0.5496.33>) stacktrace:
16:31:55.766 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:104(<0.5496.33>) st: lager_trunc_io:alist/3 at (448)
16:31:55.766 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:104(<0.5496.33>) st: lager_trunc_io:alist/3 at (418)
16:31:55.766 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:104(<0.5496.33>) st: lager_trunc_io:print/3 at (168)
16:31:55.766 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:104(<0.5496.33>) st: lager_trunc_io:map_bodyc/3 at (359)
16:31:55.766 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:104(<0.5496.33>) st: lager_trunc_io:map_bodyc/3 at (361)
16:31:55.766 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:104(<0.5496.33>) st: lager_trunc_io:map_body/3 at (348)
16:31:55.766 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:104(<0.5496.33>) st: lager_trunc_io:print/3 at (285)
16:31:55.766 [error] |1aee60d7-7e93-4d70-8bbd-b1f647915d45|kz_util:104(<0.5496.33>) st: lager_trunc_io:list_body/4 at (311)
```

Sending the push mannualy, it works, so the certificate should be right.

Any advice? I did the same with FCM for Android and works like a charm.

Comment: It complains that the process `apns_sup` is not running. Is the `apns` application started? You can check with `application:which_applications()` in the Erlang shell.

Comment: If I run `erl` and `application:which_applications().` I got this: `[{stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.12.1"}, {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","6.5.2.1"}]`. So, it seems not running. How do I can start it? Thank you

Comment: You can start it with `apns:start()`. You may want to declare that your application depends on the `apns` application, in order to have it start automatically - if you're using rebar3, see the [Building a Project with Dependencies](https://adoptingerlang.org/docs/development/dependencies/#building-a-project-with-dependencies) section of "Adopting Erlang".

Comment: You're right, the process is off because crash on start. It'a already included into the `pusher.app.src` between the applications. It give this error on start: `gen_statem 'apns' in state connected terminated with reason: {'function not exported',{string,lowercase,1}} in gun:normalize_headers/1 line 661` and `CRASH REPORT Process 'apns' with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function string:lowercase(<<"apns-expiration">>)`

Comment: `string:lowercase` was added in Erlang/OTP 20.0. Are you using an earlier Erlang release?

Comment: erl console give me `Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.7.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]`. If I execute `string:lowercase("apns-expiration").` in console it return the right result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242077/discussion-between-darion-badlydone-and-legoscia).